# I want to check the clicked element is this element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is('#clickedElement')) {
    console.log('this is clicked');
  } else {
    console.log('somewhere else clicked');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-options-icon"><i class="far fa-trash" id="clickedElement"></i></div>
```

Want to check whether the div is clicked else somewhere is clicked using this way. Really appreciate your help, explain if possible.Thanks <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a jQuery `function` event handler, `this` will refer to the element you attached the listener to. Here, it's `document`, so that's what `this` is.

```js
$(document).on('click', function() {
  console.log(this === document);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-options-icon"><i class="far fa-trash" id="clickedElement">click</i></div>
```

Check if the `event.target` (which will point to the element the event was dispatched to - the innermost element) is the clicked element instead.

```js
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('#clickedElement')) {
    console.log('this is clicked');
  } else {
    console.log('somewhere else clicked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-options-icon"><i class="far fa-trash" id="clickedElement">click</i></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain me why we use $() in the e.target?

Comment: I was only copying your approach, which was using jQuery's `is`. You must use `$` to call jQuery. But there's no need for that if you don't want to. You could instead do `if (e.target.id === 'clickedElement')`

Comment: Thankyou so much really understood